# Finding an index of one of alternative keywords

Tags: python

I have an input string, which looks like:

`input_string = "word1 word2     word3  word5 key1 word6    word7"`

I have to check whether it contains one of a list of given keywords

`keywords = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3' ]`

and set value of a variable to the index of that keyword in the string or None otherwise. E.g. in the `input_string` above it would be 4.

My current solution looks like this:

```
try:
    key_index = input_string.split().index(filter(lambda x: x in input_string.split(), keywords).__next__())
    return_value = key_index
except (StopIteration, ValueError):
    return_value = None
```

Alternative, iterative version would look like this:

```
n = 0
return_value = None
words = input_string.split()
for w in words:
  if w in keywords:
    return_value = n
    break
  else:
    n += 1
```

Or:

```
return_value = None
for k in keywords:
  if k in input_string.split():
    try:
      return_value = input_string.split().index(k)
    except ValueError:
      pass
```

All of these solutions seem somewhat clumsy for such a simple problem. I am looking for a more elegant solution, preferably in a functional style. python3.x only solutions are ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension

```
>>> [i for i, j  in enumerate(input_string.split()) if j in keywords]
[4]
>>>
```

You can also use `index`

```
>>> [input_string.split().index(i) for i in keywords if i in input_string.split()]
[4]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna ONLY the first idx:

```
for idx, value in enumerate(input_string.split()):
    if value in keywords:
        break
else:
    idx = None
```

`else` would be process only if `for` completed without `break`

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of indexes for the keys that are in the string:

```
indexes = [input.index(key) for key in keys if key in input]
```

Comment: I need to have an index of the key in the string. Not just whether it contains a keyword.

Comment: This answer is the same as mine